# Is there a simple pythonic way to increase variables while unpacking a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I want to do something like:

```
a,b,c,d = 1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d += 2,4,6,8
```

But this does not work.  I know I can increase them individually but I thought there would be a simpler way.  The only alternative I came up with was this ugly list comprehension:

```
a,b,c,d = [j+k for idxj,j in enumerate((a,b,c,d)) for idxk,k in enumerate((2,4,6,8)) if idxj==idxk]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi Jimi:  I like the syntax that you are proposing ( that is, a,b,c,d += 2,4,6,8 ).  It's terse and easy to read.  Of course, the correct one-liner that you provided is indeed ugly.  Let's translate ugly ( which is accurate ) to something more descriptive:  difficult to maintain.  I think that if you were dealing with only 4 variables, you might as well increase them individually -- because it's easy to read.  If you had a lot of variables, you might consider using some collection ( depending on whatever your program requires ).  In a nutshell, keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), generally:

```
a, b, c, d = [x + y for x, y in zip((a, b, c, d), (2, 4, 6, 8))]
```

but there’s also our friend the semicolon:

```
a += 2; b += 4; c += 6; d += 8
```

Replace with a newline at your discretion.